# SSRS repeating background image issue

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, background-image

I have a report which uses a background gradient, this is repeated horizontally but not vertically. For some reason, when it is displayed there is a line across the bottom of the image that mirrors the top of the image, as if it was going to repeat, similar to edge smoothing in anti-aliasing.

[image]

I have an extreme example shown here, its not a border as borders are orange, background colour is set to yellow so not that, it isn't actually repeating down the page so not that either.

Since in the report the gradient merges down into the background colour we end up with a line between the two, which while not the end of the world, looks unprofessional.

I am using visual studio 2008, with the BIDS add in. Settings for the image are pulled from database, as shown here:
[image]

Does anyone have ideas on the cause/solution to this?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a sort of solution - Or to be more exact have tracked this down.

The problem here is the SSRS renderer in VS2008. Once the report was deployed and rendered through IE the problem went away.  So while an annoyance in development its not an issue once pushed live.

[image]